# Laravel 5.1 import csv to mysql database failed

Tags: php, mysql, csv, laravel-5.1, import-from-excel

I got this error

```
ErrorException in PolicyOwnerController.php line 146:
fopen(http://localhost:8000/upload/import/20150828120803_import.csv): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

PolicyOwnerController.php line 146 contained this code:

```
if (($handle = fopen(asset('upload/import/'.$filename), "r")) !== FALSE) {
```

I guess it has permission issue, so I run:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 public/upload/import
```

but same result. Any idea?

Comment: Check if you can open http://localhost:8000/upload/import/20150828120803_import.csv in your browser. Does the file actually exist?

Comment: yes, it already upload, Im uploading it first then read it

Comment: Check your php.ini for the `allow_url_fopen` setting.

Comment: I have checked it, it says `allow_url_fopen = On`

Comment: Check if safe mode is off in php.ini.